# Spying on a USB connection on Windows?

Tags: windows, usb, serial-port, arduino

I have an Arduino application talking over USB to an application on Windows 8 using the [MAVLINK](http://qgroundcontrol.org/mavlink/start) protocol. The connection appears as COM3.

Is there a Windows application that can spy on this connection and display the traffic going in both directions? Raw bytes are fine, I don't need the protocol decoded.

Comment: Use SysInternals' PortMon utility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can use Windows XP in your environment, [USB sniff](http://www.pcausa.com/Utilities/UsbSnoop/) should work for you. If you need something more powerful (and are willing to pay a fee for it) then [USBLyzer](http://www.usblyzer.com/) might be a viable option.

Answer (score 6):

You could log serial port activity using [Portmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896644). (Edit: You need to first connect to the local computer via the Computer menu, and you must start capture on the port before a program opens it.)

You may not want to log USB traffic. Such a log would include a lot of extra information relating to the USB to serial adapter which is providing COM3. Portmon would only give you the bytes transferred over COM3, and the Mavlink protocol is entirely contained within that data stream. If you're sure you want to log all USB traffic to and from that device, then I recommend [SnoopyPro](http://sourceforge.net/projects/usbsnoop/). In Windows 7, you need to run it as administrator.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is SnoopyPro, and you can download it at:

[SnoopyPro Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/usbsnoop/)

This tool allows you to get USB information and also USB communication data. I used it in the past to know how a USB device worked in order to do its driver on Linux. I used this tool as a sniffer.

Basically, SnoopyPro allows you to intercept, display, record and analyze the USB protocol and all transferred data between any USB device connected to your PC and applications. It can be successfully used in application development, USB device driver or hardware development and offers the powerful platform for effective coding, testing and optimization.

Comment: You can add in your answer some features and what exactly does this app do, to make your answer more efficient.

Comment: This application was able to reliably and easily capture USB packets and worked well.

Comment: What version of Windows did you try it on? Windows 7 64-bit?

Comment: Windows 10 64bit